# VBA code to Vlookup with Concat function from another Workbook till the last row

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

There are 2 files. Input file(.xlsb format) and Code file.

In Code file, I want a VBA Code where the excel asks for Input file location which is in xlsb format.

Apply Vlookup in CL column of Input file

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(U2,V2,AJ2,AK2,AL2),[Code file.xlsx]Sheet99'!$D:$Q,14,0)
```

till the end of row of column D of Input file.

Once completed. Message box should appear as "Done".

Please help.

I tried the below code:

```
Sub ProcessData()
    Dim inputFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsMap As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Ask for input file path
    inputFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb), *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsb", Title:="Select Input File")
    
    ' Exit if user cancels the file selection
    If inputFile = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open the input file
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(inputFile)
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets(1) ' Assuming the data is in the first sheet
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column D
    lastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Concatenate values in CL column
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        wsData.Cells(i, "CL").Value = wsData.Cells(i, "U").Value & _
                                       wsData.Cells(i, "V").Value & _
                                       wsData.Cells(i, "AJ").Value & _
                                       wsData.Cells(i, "AK").Value & _
                                       wsData.Cells(i, "AL").Value
    Next i
    
    ' Fetch information from 'Sheet99' sheet
    Set wsMap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet99")
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Assuming the data in 'Micro Segment Map' sheet starts from row 2
        wsData.Cells(i, "CM").Value = Application.VLookup(wsData.Cells(i, "CL").Value, wsMap.Range("D:Q"), 14, False)
    Next i
       
    ' Display "Done" message
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I want a VBA Code where the excel asks for Input file location which is in xlsb format.

Apply Vlookup in CL column of Input file

=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(U2,V2,AJ2,AK2,AL2),[Code file.xlsx]Sheet99'!$D:$Q,14,0)
till the end of row of column D of Input file.

Once completed. Message box should appear as "Done".